# What control should I use for showing "Featured Products" on my ASP.net Website?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have various SQL tables and my use case is:

I'll choose 5 Products at random and they'll show in X control (don't know what to use here).

I know I'll have to use SQL and pull the product information using the ProductID as the hook to fish out every other information.

What Control should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---If you want to show random product, then Adrotator is the best choice

---If you are getting product randomly from DB then Repeater or datalist could be the best choice

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want do display it.

Maybe a Repeater and ObjectDataSource will be useful, depending on your ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx), maybe a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx). explain more about what you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities spring to my half-asleep mind.

the first would be to use a ListView or Repeater and have it themed out appropriately.

The second possibility would be to create a user control that displays the way you want, and then instantiate 5 instances on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a user control that would take an array of ids as a property.  Encapsulated in the user control would be everything you need to do to display your products.  This would probably be an array of panels with images and labels.